# Examples of complete families of functions forming an absolutely convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, orthogonality, absolute-convergence

I am searching for some examples of complete families of functions $\left\{ \phi_m(t) \right\}_{m = 1}^\infty$ on $t \in [0, T]$ that form an absolutely convergent series:
$$
\sum_{m = 1}^\infty |\phi_m(t)| < \infty, ~~~~ t \in [0, T].
$$

According to the Weierstrass M-test, $\phi_m$ must satisfy
$$
|\phi_m(t)| \leq c_m, ~~ t \in [0, T],
$$
such that
$$
\sum_{m = 1}^\infty c_m < \infty.
$$

Any idea or references would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you work in the Hilbert space $L^2([0,T])$? What is the precise definition of a complete family?

Comment: Yes, let the space be $L^2$. By complete family I mean
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Complete_system_of_functions

Comment: So you work in $L^2([0,T])$, but the $\phi_m$ must be $L^\infty([0,T]) \cap L^2([0,T])$.

Comment: Weirstrass $M$-test is an _if_ theorem. You can have a series $\sum f_n$ that converges absolutely uniformly but $\sum\sup|f_n|=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of complete system in the link provided, $\{\phi_m\}$ must be an orthonormal system. This implies among other things that$\int_0^T|\phi_m|^2\,dt=1$. Suppose that there is a constant $M>0$ such that
$$
|\phi_m(t)|\leq M\quad\forall t\in[0,T]\quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{m=1}^\infty\int_0^T|\phi_m(t)|\,dt\leq M.
$$
This holds in particular if $|\phi_m(t)|\leq c_m$ with $\sum_{m=1}^\infty c_m<\infty$. Then
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty|\phi_m(t)|^2\le M\sum_{m=1}^\infty|\phi_m(t)|,\quad0\le t\le T.
$$
Integrating we get $\infty$ on the left hand side, and $M^2$ on the right hand side, a contradiction.
This shows that no such families exist.

Comment: In other words, there are complete families of $\phi_m(t)$ that are bounded but their series is not absolutely convergent. That's clear. I am more interested in examples of $\phi_m$ the series of which is absolutely convergent.

Comment: What I showed is that such families do not exist.

Comment: My question could be too primitive for you, but I am just trying to understand. My understanding of your answer, is that there might be a family $\{\phi_m\} \in L^1[0, T]$ whose series is not absolutely convergent. I agree with that. But since not every family $\{\phi_m\}$ with
$$
|\phi_m(t)| \leq c_m, ~~ \sum_{m = 1}^\infty c_m < \infty,
$$
satisfies
$$
\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \int_0^T |\phi_m(t)| dt < \infty,
$$
I think we can't claim that such families do not exist at all.

Comment: On the other hand, for every family satisfying
$$
|\phi_m(t)| \leq c_m, ~~ \sum_{m = 1}^\infty c_m < \infty,
$$
we have
$$
\sum_{m = 1}^\infty |\phi_m(t)| < \infty.
$$
Integrating
$$
|\phi_m(t)|^2 \leq c_m^2,
$$
over $t \in [0, T]$, we obtain that if, in addition,
$$
c_m^2 \geq \frac{1}{T},
$$
then $\{\phi_m\}$ can be orthonormal.